# Why does the deprecation warning appear when using the label method?

Tags: ruby, page-object-gem

A DEPRECATION WARNING appears when I run following code:

```
 class MatchingPage
    include PageObject
    include Watir

    div(:choose_competitor_dialog, :class => 'dijitDialogPaneContentArea pf-matching-competitors-dlg')

    def competitor_name_select (name)
        self.choose_competitor_dialog_element.label(:text => name).parent.checkbox(:class => 'dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput').set
    end

  end


  on(MatchingPage) do |matching_page|
    matching_page.competitor_name_select 'shop.com'
  end
```

The warning says:

> *** DEPRECATION WARNING**
>    You are calling a method named label at /home/spoonest/workspace/csv_ui_checker/pages.rb:77:in
>   `competitor_name_select'.
>    **This method does not exist in page-object so it is being passed to the driver.**
>    This feature will be removed in the near future.
>    **Please change your code to call the correct page-object method.
>   *** If you are using functionality that does not exist in page-object please request it be added.

How can I locate the label element without getting this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a Page Object element does not know a method called, in this case `label`, the method is delegated to the underlying Watir (or Selenium) element. When this happens, you will get the warnings.

To locate a child label element, the method is called `label` in Watir. However, to avoid the warning in the page object gem, it should be `label_element`:

```
def competitor_name_select (name)
  self.choose_competitor_dialog_element.label_element(:text => name).parent.checkbox(:class => 'dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput').set
end
```